# UFW Preventing Web Browsing

Tags: debian, networking, firewall, ufw

I have the following rule set configured using UFW on Debian Jessie 8.2.0:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
20,21,22,53,80,442/tcp     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
20,21,22,53,80,442/udp     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
20,21,22,53,80,442/tcp     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
20,21,22,53,80,442/udp     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

When I disable UFW, web browsing in Iceweasel works correctly. Once enabled, it appears to be blocking all web traffic. I have tried accessing web pages utilizing the IP address retrieved via PING - to no avail.

My understanding is that the set rules are exceptions to the "deny (outgoing)". Hence, port 53 should allow the DNS request, while 80 and 443 subsequently allow HTTP and HTTPS traffic.

I was utilizing this exact same rule set on another Debian Jessie box, without issue.

Comment: Your text writes as `443` (correct), but the shaded output log showing `442` (wrong) which means just typo?